# how can i fix InvalidArgumentError : input and filter must have the same depth: 3 vs 32?

Tags: keras-layer

My image data size is too small(about 100), so I use ImagDataGenerator for augmentation.
I don't know why error is
for image classification(4 category), i use convolution.
I think cause of error is input_shape.
input vs  filter -> 3: 42 what is mean? How can I fix my code?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3) padding = 'same', input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

...

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 16

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'picture/train/makkne',  
        target_size=(150, 150),  
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')  

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'picture/test/makkne',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=15,
        validation_data=test_generator,
        epochs=50)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error log too?

Comment: WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-6-6226f26503de>:1: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
Epoch 1/50

Comment: InvalidArgumentError:  input and filter must have the same depth: 3 vs 32
  [[node sequential/activation_1/Relu (defined at <ipython-input-6-6226f26503de>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1085]

Function call stack:
train_function